# html table column resizing when adding sub-table on cell

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

I have a html with some data and a row with a colspan of the number of columns to get the full width of the table. This colspan row can appear or disappear like a tree table. I'm using jquery and an inner div to do it.

```
<table id="mainTable" style="width:100%">
  <thead> 6 headers... </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
             6 columns with some data...
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="6">
      <div id="toShow" style="display:none;">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>small text></td>
          <!-- long text seems to be more inclined to provoke this behavior -->
          <td>looooonnng text</td>
        </tr>   
     </table>
     </div>
     </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

```
 $('#mainTable').on("click", function(){
    $('#toShow').toggle();
 });
```

So this work pretty well as long as the row does not contain a table.
Otherwise columns of the parent table get resized when row appear/disappear.
Firefox doesn't seems affected by this behavior and everything works pretty well.
I'm absolutely unable to figure out why but like I said on the comment long text seems more inclined to provoke this behavior it must trigger some repaint/rebuild on the browser.

Here is a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/w6SME/

Also a `table-layout: fixed` may fix the problem but I would like not to use it, I want column's width to adapt according to their content.

Comment: Dude that's a teribble layout. You have `table` inside a `div` inside a `td`. How about something like **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/w6SME/2/)**?

Comment: Your jsfiddle is a totally different layout. I really need a sub-table with different number of column, header (I've cut off header in jsfiddle to make it simple), border etc... The div is here to permit animation on table row.